# C# DataGridView Selection mode: Cell Select - is it possible to retrieve a specific column value for that selected row?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have been using `FullRowSelect` for all DataGridView's.

And I'd retrieve the data from DataGridView like so:

```
tableGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString()
```

Is it possible to use Selection mode: `CellSelect` and get a specific column for that particular selected cell row?

For example, I know my 1st column (`column[0]`) is an `id` number. And using `CellSelect` clicking it on any of the columns other that the `id` column, retrieve the `id` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any single `DataGridViewCell` will have a row and col index. If the selection mode is `CellSelect`, you could get the “selected” cells address a couple of different ways. The grids `SelectedCells` collection is available when the grids selection mode is set to `CellSelect` or any other mode….

```
DataGridViewCell cell = DataGridView1.SelectedCells[0];
```

Also, with any selection mode set, the grid maintains a `CurrentCell` property. Which “usually” is the currently selected cell, which would usually be the “last” selected cell if multi-select is set to `true`…

```
DataGridViewCell cell = DataGridView1.CurrentCell;
```

Then the `cell` variable has a `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` property…

```
Int rowIndex = cell.RowIndex;
Int colIndex = cell.ColumnIndex;
```

Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes that's perfect! Now I can do something like this `dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()` to get the `ID`.